# Auto refresh label in MVC View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an auto refresh method (something like below) in my controller. In which I will update data in `ViewBag`, which I use in label of view. But I'm unable to refresh my label automatically. Please help me.

```
var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle,(state, timeout) => 
{
    // my viewbag
    viewbag.time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    viewbag=date
}, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC doesn't work like WebForms (where reassigning a value populates to the UI). You'll need to write a separate action (or WebAPI method) and use AJAX/JavaScript to pull updates. (Alternatively you could use SignalR, but that may be overkill).

Also, if this is a recurring event, you may want to look into a library like Quartz.NET to perform the action. Then, post updates to a shared resource (looks like you're storing timestamp of last execution). From there, use `setInterval`/AJAX on the client to retrieve and display that value.

Comment: Thanks for Quick response, could you suggest me some sample codes

Comment: @user3414462: https://github.com/bchristie/StackOverflow-Examples/tree/question-27401977

Comment: Thats really a great one. But i'm unable to figure out few things.
1. How it is refreshing after every 5sec. I guess its through script below index page. But I'm unable to figure out how.
2. <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>, you mentioned like, this is a dynamically-generated library based on the Hubs. With out the physical file of "~/signalr/hubs", how it is working. Can i use same reference in my project.

Comment: SignalR uses something similar to PUSH notifications so when something happens on the server the client receives it immediately. The 5 second delay is because that's the delay set for that SimpleJob (every time the job runs it sends something to the client). ~/signalr/hubs is a file, it's just written by the server and isn't a static file (like jquery, for example). And yes, you would reference jquery, jquery.signalr and ~/signalr/hubs in your own project.

Comment: Sorry, i'm unable to find where you set delay for SimpleJob. Help me to modify that value

Comment: In ~/App_Config/QuartzConfig.cs

Comment: When i'm implementing this code in my project getting an exception. "uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'SimpleHub' of undefined". I googled and tried many solutions but unable to figure out.